# Assigning shapes to a group in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

### Added this paragraph below after the solution was found to add the full context just in case its useful to others

I have a set of slides with a lot of grouped shapes.  The groups are all named for identification. I need to make changes to the layout of the shapes in the groups and its much easier if I ungroup them.  The challenge is a) making sure when regrouping them all the original shapes are included and b) the original group name is lost when regrouped. So the first macro ungroups the shapes and stores the group name in an offslide textbox and all the shape names in a second offslide text box. The code below is to recreate that grouping once the changes have been made

If I have a list of shape names, how can I add them to a group using VBA.  The list of shape names is dynamic, ie the names of the shapes and number of shapes can change each time I run the code.

For example, I have a list of shape names "shape1", "shape2", "shape3", "shape4". They are in a string array.  I loop through the array adding each shape into a shape array but I can't get the .Group method to work. I have tried passing the list of shaped to group as strings, shape arrays... but so far no luck

```
    'Using a static example to keep it simple but this list of shapes can change
    strContents = "shape1,shape2,shape3,shape4)"
    strGroupMembers = Split(strContents, ",")
    ReDim shpArray(0 To UBound(strGroupMembers) - 1)
    
    For intCounter = 0 To UBound(strGroupMembers) - 1
        Set shpArray(intCounter) = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(strGroupMembers(intCounter))
    Next
    'This line is causing the error
    ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(shpArray).Group
```

I have tried to pass the list of shapes to the group method as a comma delimited string in a variable, and now trying to create an array of shapes and passing that argument but will always get a object required error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Range` method takes an array of strings. Since you didn't declare it, it became an array of variants instead.

```
Dim strGroupMembers() As String
strContents = "shape1,shape2,shape3,shape4"
strGroupMembers = Split(strContents, ",")

ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(strGroupMembers).Group
```

Another way:

```
shpArray = Array("shape1", "shape2", "shape3", "shape4")
ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(shpArray).Group
```

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I did have the string declaration further up the code but there was some other stuff in there so I was trying to keep it simple.  I tried to implement your solution but it wouldn't work - kept getting a shape not found error for shape4.  I put your code into a new Sub and it worked.  So, back to my old code body but again, didn't work. The names of the shapes are stored in a Textbox on the slide. I forced the name of the shapes (strContents = "shape1,shape2,shape3,shape4") and it worked but that string was identical to the shape names. Deleted shape4, drew it again - its working

Comment: @Ben, have a careful look at the declaration of `strContents`. Especially the last two characters

Answer (score 0):

Now its working, I'm trying to give the group a name. Rather than group it immediately I assigned it to an object variable, and tried to use the group method, but keep getting an error :

```
'ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(strGroupMembers).Group    
Dim objGroup As Shape    
Set objGroup = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(strGroupMembers)    
objGroup.Group '<--- Error - method not found.
objGroup.Name = "Test"
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test this but try Set objGroup = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Range(strGroupMembers).Group then delete the objGroup.Group line.

Comment: Great!  Now for the repayment:  Please indicate the correction in your original post and mark it answered. That way others with the same problem will find the fix more easily.  Thanks!